# How can I correctly save transformable objects in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios14

I’m building an app that uses core data. There I save arrays of strings, UIColor and UIImage. All with transformable types.
However I noticed I get the following error:

> ’NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release

I found and implemented a few demonstrations [like this one](https://danielbernal.co/coredata-transformable-and-nssecurecoding-in-ios-13/) and I was wondering if these were the best solutions to get rid of the error.
Everything seems to work pretty good  but, for me, it did using  transformables as well until I saw that error.
So I’m looking for the correct way to save these transformable types in core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked article covers the topic very well. The log in the console you are getting is not an error, but a warning. We have encountered the same issue and every solution points to using `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData` which in fact seems to be a correct one for the problem. We have been using it in production for quite a while now and everything works as expected and the warning is gone. And you should be treating it for what it is, a warning. It it does resurface at any time for some specific type that you are trying to store in your CoreData, you could try implementing a custom transformer just like its shown in the article. Good luck!