# Can UIColor be persisted in SwiftData

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm trying to persist a data model which contains a property of the type `UIColor` via SwiftData. I followed [a tutorial][1] to use the `@Attribute(.transformable(by: UIColorValueTransformer.self)) var tileColor: UIColor?` declaration and implemented the `UIColorValueTransformer' which subclasses 'ValueTransformer`. The full code is put below.

However, Xcode throws a runtime exception with the error message "SwiftData/SchemaCoreData.swift:244: Fatal error: Unable to initialize `ValueTransformer` for UIColorValueTransformer". I have no idea how complex models like `UIColor` or `Color` can be persisted via SwiftData.

```
// Tile.swift
import SwiftData
import UIKit

@Model
final class Tile {
    @Attribute (.unique) var name: String
    var type: String
    var @Attribute(.transformable(by: UIColorValueTransformer.self)) var tileColor: UIColor?

    init(name: String, type: String, tileColor: UIColor) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.tileColor = tileColor
    }
}

final class UIColorValueTransformer: ValueTransformer {

    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return UIColor.self
    }

    // return data
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let color = value as? UIColor else { return nil }
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            return data
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    // return UIColor
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }
    
        do {
            let color = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: data)
            return color
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// TileApp.swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct TileApp: App {

    init() {
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(UIColorValueTransformer(), forName: NSValueTransformerName("UIColorValueTransformer"))
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .modelContainer(for: [Tile.self])
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.
[1]: https://azamsharp.com/2023/07/04/the-ultimate-swift-data-guide.html

Comment: https://danielbernal.co/coredata-transformable-and-nssecurecoding-in-ios-13/

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858279/how-can-i-correctly-save-transformable-objects-in-core-data. UIColor is secure archivable so there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks, @matt, for your prompt response and suggestions. I'm afraid the error in the duplicate post you provided is not the same as the one in my post. And I'm sorry I'm trying to use SwiftData instead of CoreData to persist the data model. I'd like to have further suggestions on how UIColor or even Color can be persisted via SwiftData without causing the runtime error as shown in my post.

Comment: SwiftData _is_ Core Data.

Comment: Thanks, @matt. That may be true as I have suspected. OK, I'll try integrating the CoreData way of treating transformable models.

Comment: I believe you need to add `@objc(UIColorValueTransformer)` to the `UIColorValueTransformer` class definition

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Bram! Adding that macro does stop Xcode from crashing the app with the error message in my post. But a mysterious message pops up in the console `No symbol named '' found in system symbol set`. Not sure why that is. Anyway, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @MichaelMay if you have a working solution, albeit with a warning, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @JoakimDanielson. Will do.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Bram above, the solution is as below:

```
// Tile.swift
import SwiftData
import UIKit

@Model
final class Tile {
    @Attribute (.unique) var name: String
    var type: String
    var @Attribute(.transformable(by: UIColorValueTransformer.self)) var tileColor: UIColor?

    init(name: String, type: String, tileColor: UIColor) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.tileColor = tileColor
    }
}

@objc(UIColorValueTransformer) // The solution is adding this line
final class UIColorValueTransformer: ValueTransformer {

    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return UIColor.self
    }

    // return data
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let color = value as? UIColor else { return nil }
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            return data
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

    // return UIColor
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }
    
        do {
            let color = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: data)
            return color
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// TileApp.swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct TileApp: App {

    init() {
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(UIColorValueTransformer(), forName: NSValueTransformerName("UIColorValueTransformer"))
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .modelContainer(for: [Tile.self])
        }
    }
}
```