# How to use `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and `Color` data types in Swift Data?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am converting from a [struct] to Swift Data.  Two of my elements don't seem to work in Swift Data.

### How do I make types `Color` and `CLLocationCoordinate2D` conform to `PersistentModel` and `RelationshipCollection`?

I am guessing this is either very easy or impossible.  I don't know which, and I don't know how.  Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated‼️

### Here's my code:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData
import CoreLocation
import CoreMotion
import SwiftUI


@Model
final class Item {
   var timestamp: Date
   var daCount: Int
   var gpsTimestamp: Date
   var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
   var latitude: Double
   var longitude: Double
   var myColor: Color
   
   init(timestamp: Date, daCount: Int, gpsTimestamp: Date, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, myColor: Color) {
      self.timestamp = timestamp
      self.daCount = daCount
      self.gpsTimestamp = gpsTimestamp
      self.location = location
      self.latitude = latitude
      self.longitude = longitude
      self.myColor = myColor
   }
   
}
```

When I compile I get the following six errors:

**No exact matches in call to instance method `'setValue'`**

- In expansion of macro `'_PersistedProperty'` here
- Candidate requires that `'Color'` conform to `'PersistentModel'` (requirement specified as `'Value'` : `'PersistentModel'`)
- Candidate requires that `'Color'` conform to `'RelationshipCollection'` (requirement specified as `'Value'` : `'RelationshipCollection'`)

**No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue'**

- In expansion of macro `'_PersistedProperty'` here
- Candidate requires that `'CLLocationCoordinate2D'` conform to `'PersistentModel'`
  (requirement specified as `'Value'` : `'PersistentModel'`)
- Candidate requires that `'CLLocationCoordinate2D'` conform to
  `'RelationshipCollection'` (requirement specified as `'Value'` :
  `'RelationshipCollection'`)

**No exact matches in call to instance method 'getValue'**

- In expansion of macro '_PersistedProperty' here
- Candidate requires that 'Color' conform to 'PersistentModel' (requirement specified as 'Value' : 'PersistentModel')
- Candidate requires that 'Color' conform to 'RelationshipCollection' (requirement specified as 'Value' : 'RelationshipCollection')

**No exact matches in call to instance method 'getValue'**

- In expansion of macro '_PersistedProperty' here
- Candidate requires that 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' conform to 'PersistentModel' (requirement specified as 'Value' : 'PersistentModel')
- Candidate requires that 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' conform to 'RelationshipCollection' (requirement specified as 'Value' : 'RelationshipCollection')

**No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue'**

- In expansion of macro '_PersistedProperty' here
- Candidate requires that 'Color' conform to 'PersistentModel' (requirement specified as 'Value' : 'PersistentModel')
- Candidate requires that 'Color' conform to 'RelationshipCollection' (requirement specified as 'Value' : 'RelationshipCollection')

**No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue'**

- In expansion of macro '_PersistedProperty' here
- Candidate requires that 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' conform to 'PersistentModel' (requirement specified as 'Value' : 'PersistentModel')
- Candidate requires that 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' conform to 'RelationshipCollection' (requirement specified as 'Value' : 'RelationshipCollection')

Comment: You could split `CLLocationCoordinate2D` into lat/long, and retrieve it. Same for color with rgba (for instance).

Comment: Likely duplicate, as far as the color goes, of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490973/can-uicolor-be-persisted-in-swiftdata. You would need to transform the Color to a UIColor, which is then archivable.

Comment: Color is a View it doesn’t belong in the data layer

Comment: @Larme — I did as you suggested in the short term, eliminated the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` property from my model, and reconstructed it when needed.  For color, I just stored it as a named string, which worked.  Long Term, I went with the solution below.  Thank You for helping me get over my stuck-ness. :-)

Comment: @loremipsum — I did not know that `Color` is a View.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward solution is to create custom types that conform to Codable that holds the underlying values

```
struct Coordinate2D: Codable {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}

struct RGBValues: Codable {
    let red: Double
    let green: Double
    let blue: Double
    let opacity: Double

    init(red: Double, green: Double, blue: Double, opacity: Double = 1.0) {
        self.red = red
        self.green = green
        self.blue = blue
        self.opacity = opacity
    }
}
```

They can then be used in the model directly as property types

```
@Model
final class Place {
    var name: String
    var location: Coordinate2D
    var color: RGBValues

    init(name: String, location: Coordinate2D, color: RGBValues) {
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

You can then for convenience add ways to map between your custom types and the built in types

```
extension Coordinate2D {
    init(_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.latitude = location.latitude
        self.longitude = location.longitude
    }

    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}

extension RGBValues {
    init(_ color: Color) {
        let resolvedColor = color.resolve(in: .init())
        red = Double(resolvedColor.red)
        green = Double(resolvedColor.green)
        blue = Double(resolvedColor.blue)
        opacity = Double(resolvedColor.opacity)
    }
    var color: Color {
        Color(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: opacity)
    }
}
```

Comment: …  WOW‼️  Thank you; you've taught me a lot with your answer!

Comment: … I did not know that making something `Codable` was so simple!